# Is there a way to get a png image of a site from a lidar file using R

Tags: r, geospatial

The question arose, for example, there is a lidar file (.las), I know which polygon area it belongs to and which tree species has the largest composition. For example, the file was obtained for aria `X`, the composition of the species in the area with these coordinates is `40% birch, 30% pine and 30% alder`. The question is whether it is possible to get a PNG image of this area from a .las file.
If yes, how can I do it.
Thanks for your valuable help. As example it can be used las files from this http://www.wvview.org/spatial_analytics/lidar/_site/index.html, cause my las files has size many GB.